# Query relationship arrays in Realm (android)

Tags: android, database, listview, realm

In my app, I am having trouble querying relationship arrays within an object in **realm**, the database platform I am using. For example, say you have a *person* object and, within that object, an array of *dogs*. If I have a property I can query the person with, how can I query to get that person's array of dogs? Since I am using the RealmBaseAdapter for my listview, it is important that I am chaining this as one query, because my content must update dynamically. I.e., querying the person and calling person.getDogs() would not work. Any help would be great.

Comment: you can try with something like `realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("dogs.name", "abcd");`

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your `Person` class has `firtsName` field like this:

```
public class Person extends RealmObject{

    private String firstName;
    private RealmList<Dog> dogs;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public RealmList<Dog> getDogs() {
        return dogs;
    }

    public void setDogs(RealmList<Dog> dogs) {
        this.dogs = dogs;
    }
}
```

You can get all dogs by using such a query

```
RealmList<Dog> dogs = realm.where(Person.class).equalTo("firstName", "person").findFirst().getDogs();
```